# collapsible panel in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, panel

I was trying to make collapsible panel in laravel. I am not sure how to make following line dynamic

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

I was trying to do it the following ways but it did not work

```
@foreach($cons as $con )
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><img alt="{{$con->image}}" src="{{URL::asset('albums/'.$con->image)}}" width="200" height="200"></a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse{{$con->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">{{$con->title}}</div>
  <div class="panel-footer">{!!$con->details!!}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"it did not work"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed changing the `href` on `panel-heading` link.

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <!-- Editing the HREF from original -->
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{$con->id}}"><img alt="{{$con->image}}" src="{{URL::asset('albums/'.$con->image)}}" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{$con->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">{{$con->title}}</div>
                <div class="panel-footer">{!!$con->details!!}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```